# Putnam 2018 - Exercise A.5 - proof check

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

The problem statement is as follows.

*Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be an infinitely differentiable function satisfying $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, and $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Show that there exist a positive integer $n$ and a real number $x$ such that $f^{(n)}(x)< 0$.*

---

My proof.

Suppose $f^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$ for all $x\in \Bbb R$, for all $n \in \Bbb Z^+$.

If there exists a $c < 0$ such that $f(c)>0$, then the Mean Value Theorem would give a negative derivative at some point between $c$ and $0$. So $f(x) = 0$ for $x \leq 0$, and thus, since for all $n$ $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f^{(n)}(x) = 0.$$
we must have $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$. (So far it is all like in some of the "official" proofs.)

By Taylor's Theorem (with "starting point" $0$) we have
$$f(x) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\eta_n(x))}{n!}x^n,$$
for some $\eta_n(x) \in (0,x)$. In particular
$$f(1) = \frac{f^{(n)}(\eta_n(1))}{n!} = 1,$$
which implies that there is a point $\eta_n(1)\in (0,1)$ such that $f^{(n)}(\eta_n(1)) = n!$. By monotonicity of $f^{(n)}(x)$, therefore, we must have
$$f^{(n)}(1) \geq n!.$$
Using again Taylor's Theorem (starting at $1$, this time) yields
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k!}(x-1)^k+ \frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_n(x))}{(n+1)!}(x-1)^{n+1},$$
for some $\xi_n(x) \in (1,x)$, and where $f^{(0)}(x) = f(x)$.
This gives
$$f(2) \geq n$$
for all $n\in \Bbb Z^+$, a contradiction.

---

Is my proof correct?

Comment: This looks right to me, and it is always very satisfying to see a number 5 or 6 Putnam problem taken down